# SelectionChanged is triggered in Outlook when SaveChanges for MailItem is called in VSTO add-in

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

Found strange behavior that MailItem.SaveChanges triggers Explorer.SelectionChange event in our VSTO Outlook add-in. Is it normal and is there any way to avoid that?

We tried to use OutlookRedemption, but RDOMail.Save also triggers SelectionChange.

BTW, we are calling Save from a background thread for the item found by EntryId. Is it ok to do that? Or the same restriction to use Outlook objects from the main thread only applies here? I tried to marshal calls to the main thread, but it does not help with the SelectionChange issue.

Comment: You are actually accessing OOM from a secondary thread in a VSTO addin? Are you sure it really works for you?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I get an item with rdoSession.GetMessageFromID(entryId, storeId), set some fields on RDOMail found and call rdoMail.Save. This is done from the secondary thread. I thought that in case of RDO we can do this.

Comment: Ah, yes, RDO is fine. It is OOM that is the problem.

Comment: So is the message being saved selected in Outlook?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko not always. I subscribed to Explorer.SelectionChange event. Have one message selected and background process that sets custom properties using RDO for messages in the same folder (it can hit selected message too sometimes). Seems that some RDOMail.Save causing SelectionChange to trigger. And sometimes with Selection.Count = 0.

Comment: I don' know, only Microsoft can answer that. Why does it matter that the SelectionChange event fires?

Comment: It breaks some of our flows and I did not find a way to differentiate those selections from selections done by user.

Comment: Sine the selection does not change, you can save the entry id of the selected item(s), and compare it the next time SelectionChange event fires.